# Using Pandas Dataframe within a SQL Join

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas

I'm trying to perform a SQL join on the the contents of a dataframe with an external table I have in a Postgres Database.

This is what the Dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df
   name  author  count
0  a     b       10
1  c     d       5
2  e     f       2
```

I need to join it with a Postgres table that looks like this:

```
TABLE: blog
title   author    url    
a       b         w.com
b       b         x.com
e       g         y.com
```

This is what I'm attempting to do, but this doesn't appear to be the right syntax for the query:

```
>>> sql_join = r"""select b.*, frame.*  from ({0}) frame
        join blog b
        on frame.name = b.title
        where frame.owner = b.owner 
        order by frame.count desc
        limit 30;""".format(df)

>>> res = pd.read_sql(sql_join, connection)
```

I'm not sure how I can use the values in the dataframes within the sql query.
Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

**Edit**: As per my use case, I'm not able to convert the blog table into a dataframe given memory and performance constraints.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to do this without having to convert the dataframe to a temp table or without reading SQL into a dataframe from the blog table.

For anyone else facing the same issue, this is achieved using a virtual table of sorts.

This is what my final sql query looks like this:

```
>>> inner_string = "VALUES ('a','b',10), ('c','d',5), ('e','f',2)"

>>> sql_join = r"""SELECT * FROM blog
        JOIN ({0}) AS frame(title, owner, count)
        ON blog.title = frame.title
        WHERE blog.owner = frame.owner 
        ORDER BY frame.count DESC
        LIMIT 30;""".format(inner_string)

>>> res = pd.read_sql(sql_join, connection)
```

You can use string manipulation to convert all rows in the dataframe into one large string similar to `inner_string`.

Comment: This way helped me - 

WITH my_values(num, str) AS (
    VALUES (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')
)

SELECT num, txt FROM my_values

Answer (score 2):

You should create another dataframe from the Postgres table and then join both dataframes.

You can use [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) to create a df from table:

```
import psycopg2  ## Python connector library to Postgres
import pandas as pd

conn = psycopg2.connect(...) ## Put your DB credentials here
blog_df = pd.read_sql('blog', con=conn)
## This will bring `blog` table's data into blog_df
```

It should look like this:

```
In [258]: blog_df
Out[258]: 
  title author    url
0     a      b  w.com
1     b      b  x.com
2     e      g  y.com
```

Now, you can join `df` and `blog_df` using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) like below:

```
In [261]: pd.merge(df, blog_df, left_on='name', right_on='title')
Out[261]: 
  name author_x  count title author_y    url
0    a        b     10     a        b  w.com
1    e        f      2     e        g  y.com
```

You will get result like above. You can clean it further.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) Merging dataframes is one way to go. Unfortunately, bringing the blog table in is what I'm trying to avoid doing. The table is quite large and therefore not a viable solution in my use case. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: @GenAsis - Then do it the reverse way: push data frame to Postgres and run your `JOIN` there. Use [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) via an SQLAlchemy connection.

Comment: @Parfait I considered that and It appears that might be the only way to go. I'm performing this operation quite frequently and in an ideal scenario, I don't want to be creating (temporary) tables to perform a join all the time. Is this what you meant by pushing the dataframe to postgres?

Comment: You could create the temp/staging table once and clean/populate and join to final table as regularly as needed. This would be the more efficient way as you can even set up indexing on `join` fields between staging and final table for Postgres' powerful query engine!

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, I managed to find a clean solution (that I posted below) that works for me!

Comment: Actually, why use pandas at all? Possibly you can do all your work in Postgres. You can even run Python as an extended procedural language ([pl/python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpython.html)) in Postgres' stored functions in case you need `pandas` or `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems.  I found a work-around that allows me to join two different servers where i only have read-only rights. using sqlalchemy insert the pandas dataframe and then join

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd

metadata = MetaData()
sql_of_df = sa.Table(
    "##df",
    metadata,
    sa.Column("name", sa.String(x),   primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("author", sa.String(x), nullable=False),
    sa.Columnt("count", sa.Integer),
)
metadata.create_all(engine)
dataframe_dict = df.to_dict(orient='records')
insert_statement = sql_of_df.insert().values(
    {
        "name":sa.bindparam("name"),
        "author":sa.bindparam("author"),
        "count":sa.bindparam("count"),
   }
)
session.execute(insert_statement, dataframe_dict)

statement=sa.text("SELECT * from blog Inner join ##df on blog.Title = ##df.name")
session.execute(statement)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using the SQLAlchemy package and SQLite database connection. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54173767/9195104) did not work for me. Adapting it a bit, I was able to achieve the desired result:

```
# Import packages
import pandas as pd
# from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Create sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'C']], index=None, columns=None, dtype=None)

# Create a list of tuples from the DataFrame
data = str([tuple(x) for x in df.values]).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')

# Create a SQL table from the DataFrame (incl. column names)
inner_table = """
SELECT [column1] AS column_a,
    CAST([column2] AS TEXT) AS column_b
FROM (VALUES {})
""".format(data)

# Query
query = """
SELECT table.*
FROM table
INNER JOIN ({}) AS inner_table
ON table.column_a = inner_table.column_a
""".format(inner_table)

# Read SQL table
pd.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=connection, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None)
```